# Plot the error in the curve fitting

Tags: plotting, fitting

I would like to plot the fitted model and the original data punctually. For example, I have:

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2.5}, {3, 3}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a x + b, {a, b}, x, Weights -> {1, 1, 1}]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 7}]]
```

[image]

Looking at the picture, I would like to calculate (and plot) the difference between the ordinate of line and the ordinate of the data point, for each value of the abscissa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#2 - nlm[#1] & @@@ data == nlm["FitResiduals"]
```

> True

Plotting from x = 1 to 2

```
ListPlot[nlm["FitResiduals"], Filling -> Axis,
 PlotRange -> {{1, 2}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What should I do if I wanted to limit the plot to a specific range, for example for x between 1 and 2?

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2.5}, {3, 3}};

(nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a x + b, {a, b}, x, 
    Weights -> {1, 1, 1}]) // Normal

(* 0.166667 + 1. x *)

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];

Plot[nlm[x], {x, xmin, xmax},
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[data],
   Tooltip[
      Line[{#, {#[[1]], nlm[#[[1]]]}}],
      #[[2]] - nlm[#[[1]]]] & /@ data},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 3.2}},
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One possibility to show the residues:

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2.5}, {3, 3}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a x + b, {a, b}, x, Weights -> {1, 1, 1}]
res = {#, {#[[1]], nlm[#[[1]]]}} & /@ data;
txt = Text[
     NumberForm[Norm[#[[1]] - #[[2]]], 2], #[[1]] + 
      If[#[[2, 2]] > #[[1, 2]], -1, 1] {0, .2}] & /@ res;
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 7}], 
 Epilog -> {txt, Red, Line[res]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 3.2}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]